# image wont align right

Tags: html, css

I am modifying html and css that is part of a wordpress theme:

```
<div id="featured_content">
<h1>Balance for Work and Life</h1>
<p class="flavorText">If it is having a physical impact on you or those around you, if it is weighing on your mind, affecting your emotions or stirring your spirit – whatever it is – if it is important to you, it’s important to us.<p>
<img class="angledMan" src="http://www.eap.zhi.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/angledman.png">
</div>
```

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

My problem is that the image is showing below the text but I want it to show to the right of the text.

Here is my css:

```
.flavorText {
    margin-top:2em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 21em;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    color: white;
}

.angledMan {
    float:right;
}
```

Additionally here is the associated css of the wordpress theme:

```
#header #featured #left_arrow { float: left; background: url('images/featured_before.png') no-repeat top right; width: 34px; margin-left: 7px; padding-top: 110px; height: 217px;}
#header #featured #featured_content { padding: 19px 19px 19px 40px; float: left; background: #9ebadb; width: 902px; height: 280px;  color: #000; font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.6em;}
#header #featured #featured_content img { float: left; margin: 0 30px 0 0; }
#header #featured #featured_content h1 {line-height: 1.2em; font-size: 3em; margin: 0px 0 14px 0; font-family: Century Gothic; font-weight: normal; color: #fff; text-shadow: -2px -1px 0px #000; }
#header #featured #featured_content #spotlight { float: left; width: 500px; margin-right: 10px; }
```

I've tried removing all of the float left tags above but it is still not working.

How do I get the desired result?

Comment: The h1 tag has no width set, so by default should go to the end of the div, leaving no space for the image to float beside it. Try changing the background colour to see if this is the case.

Comment: You have two choices : You float .flavortext left, or you make it inline. A paragraph tag is a block which takes the full width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change your css to this:

```
.flavorText {
    margin-top:2em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 21em;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    color: white;
    float:left;
}

.angledMan {
    float:left;
}
```

Notice, you need to `float` both classes to the **left** if you want to get this result. You can change the .angledMan to `float: right` if you want it to float all the way to the right of the screen...but you definitely need to add `float: left` to the .flavorText

http://jsfiddle.net/VkDzV/1/

Comment: this is almost it, the image on the right is a bit to low. I tried using margin and padding to adjust it higher but it's not working.

Comment: Check the fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/VkDzV/1/ the image was low because you werent floating the HEADER (h1) left, so it was taking its own line....

Answer (score 1):

Use `<div>` or `<span>` instead of `<p></p>` for the text part as `<p>` consumes entire line, set its to float:left.

Comment: A div is a block just like a p tag... if he wants anything to be inline, he can just overwrite it... (display:inline) or float the paragraph left

Answer (score 1):

You want to add

```
float: left;
```

to your CSS, like so:

```
.flavorText {
    margin-top:2em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 21em;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    color: white;
    float: left;
}

.angledMan {
    float:right;
}
```

and also close your `</p>` tag properly.

Comment: this is almost it, the image on the right is a bit to low. I tried using margin and padding to adjust it higher but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

try it without the tag

because it breaks

tag line

use span

```
<div id="featured_content">
<h1>Balance for Work and Life</h1>
<span class="flavorText">If it is having a physical impact on you or those around you, if it is weighing on your mind, affecting your emotions or stirring your spirit – whatever it is – if it is important to you, it’s important to us.</span>
<img class="angledMan" src="http://www.eap.zhi.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/angledman.png">
</div>
```